# Recover files from "partition" with DCF file system but without disk letter

Tags: windows, data-recovery, file-recovery

I'm trying to recover lost data from a complete blackout on my photo camera (strictly not a superuser question but I'm trying to solve the issue with my laptop).

So I have a camera (Canon 7D, compact flash memory card from Transcend) which is connected through USB. Upon turning on my camera, the computer will see the contents of my CF card, however, after a crash, all my data is gone.

I'm willing to explore some options I can try to retrieve the lost data, and I've tried a couple programs:

- Recuva
- Wondershare
- Remo Recover
- AsofTech
- EaseUS
- MiniTool Data Recovery
- SanDisk Rescue Pro
- Stellar Photo Recovery
- Handy Recovery
- TestDisk/PhotoRec

Now here's the funny thing, the one thing they all have in common is that they don't recognize my camera/CompactFlash card as a partition or disk to recover, so none of these will work. The problem here is that the CompactFlash card uses the "DCF" file system, something I'm also unfamiliar with.

A possible solution I thought of would be to reformat to NTFS to recover the photoes. The issue then would be that I wouldn't even know whether a format would break the card altogether (i.e., make it impossible to use/read for the camera), or whether it'd make things worse...

Another option: I could buy a CF reader to make it show up as a proper disk with a disk letter. This would be a last resort to me since I don't like buying stuff to use a single time with no guarantee whether it'll fix the issue.

Is there anything else I can try here?